# TDE's are not working due to the updated version of entity

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

Could someone help me on the below.Initially I created an entity and loaded the data and harmonized it according to the client required state.After some time ,i updated the entity definition due to the enhancement and updated the entity version as "0.0.2" as its been modified.
When i deploy the code,its automatically created the tde's with version as "0.0.2" .
I tried to harmonize the data to the entity (which has 0.0.2 version) and it stills updating the entity version as "0.0.1" in the harmonized data.Its not updating to "0.0.2".I tried to create the mapping flow using pipes.
The final envelope mapping works as expected but the version remains as "0.0.1" due to that,I'm not able to see the view data.

Tried the below steps :
Undeployed the whole DHF project and deployed it,but still no use.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datahub currently doesn't support different versions of entity.